# Adding multiple parameters to a query

Tags: c#, mysql, function

So I wish to create a nice function that will query MySQL commands in a nicer way. Something along the lines of this one:

```
    public int mysql_query_scalar(string query, parameters)
    {
            mysql_Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = mysql_connection;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterfromstring, parameternumber);

            mysql_Close();
            return int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }
```

Now, what I wish to do is to be able to add as many parameters as I can, and then start building up parameters. How is this possible? If so, please tell me or give me a snippet of it please.

I will gladly appreciate someone telling me how to use it too. I am pretty new to MySQL and I am not C# expert.

mysql_Open(); and mysql_Close(); are functions I did myself. Refer them as mysql_connection.Open(); and mysql_connection.Close();

Comment: did you try any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension method, like this:

```
public static class DbCommandExtensions
{
    public static void AddInputParameters<T>(this IDbCommand cmd,
        T parameters) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var prop in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object val = prop.GetValue(parameters, null);
            var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
            p.ParameterName = prop.Name;
            p.Value = val ?? DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Call as below :

```
cmd.AddInputParameters(new { a = textBox1.Text, b = TextBox2.Text.... });
```

Answer (score 0):

i would call this method that way:

```
List<SqlParameter> sList = new List<SqlParameter>();
sList.Add(new SqlParameter("@myValue", myValue));
sList.Add(new SqlParameter("@myValue2", myValue2));
mysql_query_scalar(myQuery, sList.ToArray());
```

and i would use using-directives

```
public static int mysql_query_scalar(string Command, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(Command, myConnection))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters); // Add Parameters here
            return (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```